# How can I achieve this formula in LaTeX?

Tags: equations

[image]

How can I achieve the formula in the picture in LaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. The language of the site is English, so it would be helpful if you could translate your question title. Also, could you be more specific about which parts of this formatting you're having trouble with? It would be helpful if you could edit your question to include a small compilable document that shows what you have so far and we can help you with the bits you're having difficulty with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would look like what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{4.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align}
        A + \delta \hat{A} &= \begin{bmatrix} \hat{Q}_t\\\hat{Q}_b\end{bmatrix} R,&& \|\delta \hat{A}\| = O (\epsilon \|A\|),\\
        \hat{Q}_t^T \hat{Q}_t + \hat{Q}_b^T \hat{Q}_b &= I_n + \Delta_1,&&\|\Delta_1\|=O(\epsilon),\\
        \hat{Q}_t^T \hat{Q}_t - \hat{Q}_b^T \hat{Q}_b &= \hat{L}^T \hat{L} + \Delta_2,&& \Delta_2^T = \Delta_2,~ \|\Delta_2\|_2 = O(\epsilon).
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, but this is the wrong approach

Comment: Unrelated: `latexsym` was last updated in 1998 and should be used only for analogously old documents. Surely not together with `amssymb`.

Comment: @egreg Could you please explain why this is wrong instead of being so toxic?

Comment: @campa Interesting, could you maybe explain where one could get problems and which package should be used instead? I think I needed it for some symbols but google says that amssymb has the missing symbols too, so I do not unterstand why I included this package some time ago

Comment: My complaint would be that you're using manual horizontal spacing.  This means that the left column of equal signs don't quite line up, and you still need lots of tweaking to get it to work.  Notice how the other answer is able to use `align` but without the hspace commands.

Comment: @question `\hspace{-1.2cm}`, I thought you'd figure out yourself. Place the `&` next to the `=` sign instead.

Comment: @Teepeemm Yeah one could do this, I normally do not line up the equality signs if I place equalitys under each other that are not equally wide, since the math can look ugly sometimes, so I just threw in some hspace to get the spacing nearly right, I think that this is not so important for the question though since he did not ask for perfect spacing but rather how one gets the formulas, but still thanks.

Comment: @egreg If your only complaint for calling my whole code "the wrong approach" is spacing, then you have some serious problems my friend.

Comment: Manually fiddling with things is the wrong approach.  The idea of LaTeX is to separate the content from the styling as much as possible, and manual spacing is not that.  OP only asked how to achieve the formula.  That might or might not include the spacing (which is why the comment asked for clarification).

Comment: @question Yes, I have the problem that when I see gratuitously bad LaTeX code, I complain. There is no reason for using a *negative* spacing computed (wrongly) by eye when TeX is perfectly able to do the *exact* computation by itself.

Comment: You won't get any errors by loading `latexsym` but it does not provide more than `amssymb`. (Few name changes, maybe, and `\Join` is defined as composite instead as single glyph.) Bottom line is that loading `latexsym` (for modern documents) has the only effect of wasting one math font; depending on which other packages you are loading this might become a problem. Why did you include the package in the past? My guess is that you looked for a symbol, found an answer saying to load `latexsym`, and the it remained in your template. That's how deprecated packages "refuse to die" `;-)`

Comment: @campa you are right, I think one of my teachers included it in a template where we needed symbols like join and I left it in since I did not want do deal with missing symbols, I will leave the package out from now on, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Like this:

[image]

With use of the `mathtools` package,  defined new delimiters pair:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm{\lVert}{\rVert}

\renewcommand{\theequation}{4.\arabic{equation}}
\setcounter{equation}{5}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align}
A + \delta \hat{A} 
    & = \begin{bmatrix} \hat{Q}_t   \\  \hat{Q}_b\end{bmatrix} R,
        &&      \norm*{\delta \hat{A}} = O (\epsilon \norm*{A}),\\
\hat{Q}_t^T \hat{Q}_t + \hat{Q}_b^T \hat{Q}_b
    & = I_n + \Delta_1,
        &&  \norm*{\Delta_1}=O(\epsilon),\\
\hspace{-1.2cm}\hat{Q}_t^T \hat{Q}_t - \hat{Q}_b^T \hat{Q}_b
    & = \hat{L}^T \hat{L} + \Delta_2,
        &&  \Delta_2^T = \Delta_2, \norm*{\Delta_2}_2 = O(\epsilon).
    \end{align}

\end{document}
```